# Redis error when using nodejs get cache data

Tags: node.js, redis

I first time use `redis` in nodejs.

```
const {createClient} = require('redis')
const redisClient = createClient({
    host: keys.redisHost,
    port: keys.redisPort,
    retry_strategy: () => 1000,
});
redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

app.get("/values/current", async (req, res) => {
    await redisClient.hGetAll("values", (err, values) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else 
        res.send(values);
    });
  });
```

I get this error:

```
/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:494
api_1       |         return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
api_1       |                               ^
api_1       |
api_1       | ClientClosedError: The client is closed
api_1       |     at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:494:31)
api_1       |     at Commander.commandsExecutor (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:189:154)
api_1       |     at BaseClass.<computed> [as hGetAll] (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
api_1       |     at /app/index.js:53:23
api_1       |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
api_1       |     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
api_1       |     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
api_1       |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
api_1       |     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
api_1       |     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
api_1       | 
api_1       | Node.js v20.9.0
api_1       | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: You are using the redis client without connecting it.

Use this code after **error event** registration 
`await redisClient.connect()`